# Jest doMock the same method multiple times

Tags: node.js, jestjs

I would like to test following part of the code:

```js
// ... code above

const created = async payload => {
  const model = await db.collection('models').doc(payload.model)
    .get() // <--- 1st .get() occurence

  if (!model.exists) {
    // Add product to the orphans collection
    await db.collection('orphans').doc(payload.sku).set(payload)
  } else {
    // Grab the categories field
    const categories = model.get('categories') // <--- 2nd .get() occurence

    // Product is either empty or does not exists at all
    if (!categories || categories.length < 1) {
      // Add product to the orphans collection
      await db.collection('orphans').doc(payload.sku).set(payload)
    } else {
      // Otherwise remove from the orphans collection
      await deleted(payload.sku)
    }
  }
}
```

I do not know how to properly mock the file twice in the same callback. Here is what I get:

```js
test.only('it should react when an event "created" has been fired', async () => {
  const spy = jest.fn()
  jest.doMock('@google-cloud/firestore', () => class {
    collection () {
      return {
        doc: () => {
          return {
            get: () => {
              return {
                exists: () => {
                  spy()
                }
              }
            },

            set: () => {
              spy()
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  })

  const observer = require('./product')
  await observer('created', {})

  await expect(spy.mock.calls.length).toBe(1)
})
```

I get this error:

```sh
  ● it should react when an event "created" has been fired

    TypeError: model.get is not a function

      25 |   } else {
      26 |     // Grab the categories field
    > 27 |     const categories = model.get('categories')
         |                              ^
      28 |
      29 |     // Product is either empty or does not exists at all
      30 |     if (!categories || categories.length < 1) {

      at created (app/observers/product.js:27:30)
      at Object.<anonymous>.module.exports (app/observers/product.js:6:28)
      at Object.<anonymous> (app/observers/product.spec.js:34:3)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 skipped, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        0.147 s, estimated 1 s
Ran all test suites matching /app\/observers\/product.spec.js/i.
```

What is the working solution to test two scenarios of the same mocked `get()` method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code :

```js
const model = await db.collection('models').doc(payload.model)
    .get() // <--- 1st .get() occurence
```

If we look at your mock, the `get` method of `doc` returns :

```js
              {
                exists: () => {
                  spy()
                }
              }
```

There are no property named `get`, so it is `undefined` (and not a function).

I guess you just have to change this part to :

```js
              {
                exists: true, // can be false
                get: spy,
              }
```

And your problem should be solved.

Btw, you can also change the mock of `set` method to `set: spy`. Or you can keep it to `set: () => { spy() }`, but you should at least return the value if you want to mock it : `set: () => { spy() }`.

Now, about how to properly mock multiple times, here's what you can do :

```js
const observer = require('./product')

const spyGet = jest.fn()
const spySet = jest.fn() // I like having different mocks, if one function use get & set, tests will be clever & more readable if you use different spies

describe('on event "created" fired', () => {
  const categories = []

  beforeEach(() => {
    // I put mocks here to make test more readable
    jest.doMock('@google-cloud/firestore', () => class {
      collection () {
        return {
          doc: () => {
            return {
              get: () => {
                return {
                  exists: true,
                  get: spyGet,
                }
              },
              set: spySet
            }
          }
        }
      }
    })
    spyGet.mockResolvedValueOnce(categories) // you can also use mockResolvedValue, but mockResolvedValueOnce allow you to mock with different values on the same test & same mock
  })

  it.only('should get categories', async () => {
    await observer('created', {})

    // here's all the ways you can test it
    expect(spyGet).toBeCalledTimes(1)
    expect(spyGet.mock.calls.length).toBe(1)
    expect(spyGet).toBeCalledWith('categories')
    expect(spyGet).toHaveBeenNthCalledWith(1, 'categories')
  })
})
```

**Note :** You should reset & clear your mocks between tests manually (in a afterEach or beforeEach) if you don't set it into jest config.

Comment: Thank you Robin  for such simple and perfect explanation ! It works great.